# Duplicate SCSI HHD to SATA SSD

Tags: scsi

I got the Cavalry Dual Bay SATA Hard Drive Duplicator Docking Station and it works great when I Clone/Duplicate SATA Hard Drives but I have a couple of SCSI HHDs that I want to Clone/Duplicate but the connectors are not the same and I don't know what cable or adapter if any I can/should get to make it work, or if there is anything I can get for $150 or less if possible to get this done.

Can someone please help me out and let me know if there is anything out there that will get this done for me, I would like to use the Station VS a software solution.

Thank you so much for any help!

( The SCSI HHD I have is: 15k Ultra 320 SCSI 80 Pin )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 80 pins you probably have a SCA connector. Can you verify that it looks the same as in the picture below?

[image]
<sup>Image courtesy of [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SCSIHardDriveConnectors.jpg)</sup>

To connect such a drive you need a SCSI hostadapter (in sales droid terms: A SCSI controller).  Once you have that you need a proper backplane or a caddy to mount it in (SCA drives are usually used in hot-swap backplanes) and then you can duplicate it with normal disk cloning software.  (E.g. Clonezilla, Norton Ghost, Acronis trueimage, or just use plain single `dd`, `cp` or `cat` on a raw unix device).

Comment: Yes This is exactly how it looks.

Comment: but is there anything I can buy that I can convert the 80 pin SCA Connector? to a SATA ? I would really love to do that if at all possible because I already have the copy/duplicator hardware. Thanks again.

Comment: You can turn 80 pins SCA back to 68 pins ('wide') SCSI plus a power connector. But not into IDE or SATA. There is quite a difference between the two. (IDE is a drive plus controller  (or in the case of IDE for up to two drives), SCSI is a protocol for drives, CPU's serial ports, optical drives etc etc. And not just for two of them but for up to 16 devices per 16 bit wide bus. It might be possible to build a specific SCSI disk copy station, but using a simple PC is probably much more practical.

Comment: In the case of a unix-alike PC: Connect both disks: Boot (E.g. from a liveCD, and `cp /dev/sda /dev/sdb` to copy the first SCSI disk to an identical second SCSI disk. (or use `cat /dev/sda > /dev/sdb`, or `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=1M`. Lots of working ways when the disk is treated as just a file).

Comment: Got it, Thanks for helping me, I understand this a lot better now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have Acronis TrueImage for disk-to-disk copy , partition copy, sector-by-sector which is really fast.

Comment: Please be more specific how that recommendation is of use in this situation. Take a look [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers) for some advice on how to recommend software properly.